# Search Field for Table with Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm fairly new to Rails, but have an extensive Java/C++ background and am working on a project where I display a search box and a table using the following html:

```
<h2>Search ID</h2>
  <%= form_tag do %>
  <%= label_tag :user_id, "User ID" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :user_id %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
  <% end %>
<h2>List of People</h2>
<div>
  <table id="people_list" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User Name</th>
      <th>ID Number</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% Users.each do |user| %>
        <tr><td><%= user.name %></td><td><%= user.id_number %></td></tr>
      <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

What I want is a search box that will allow you to essentially "query" the table with a user_id and give back the user. Ideally I would like to do this without redirecting to a new page when the search button is pressed.

Is it possible to dynamically show a row of the table underneath the search bar and above the table if a search is done? If so, how would I do this in the `html.erb` file? What method would the search button go to in my controller? I imagine it would be different than the method that my table uses to populate itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used any but have heard about these.

[elasticsearch](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails) and [thinking-sphinx](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx)

or (a thought) U could make ajax calls and return the result through json object.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find an ajax way of doing it, this method renders the page again with the search criteria included. There is a RailsCast - Simple Search that runs through a simple search form that is included at the top of the page. Otherwise, there is gem called Ransack that allows a bit more complexity for search forms.

Hopefully these resources are of some use.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form

http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack